# Java: comparing 2 numbers and eliminating the lower one

Tags: java

I am working on my homework assignment and I faced a problem where I do not know how to code what is in my head. The input is an unknown amount of numbers.

INPUT(example): 1 2 2 3 4 10 4 3 4 5 6 7 10 11 11 11 11 5 6 7 8 9 10

OUTPUT: The output has to be the largest number of different numbers in a row(definition in next line). I cant phrase this better but you might understand what i mean later. I will refer to the number of different numbers as NODN

ROW definition: 1 row is considered as long as the next input is not lower than the previous one. In the example we have 4 rows:

1 2 2 3 4 10,
4,
3 4 5 6 7 10 11 11 11 11,
5 6 7 8 9 10

The desired output would be 7, as the 3rd row would have the largest number of different numbers.

I am only allowed to use Scanner, int and boolean types. The first part of the code(at least i believe so) gets the NODN in the first row and the second part gets the number from second row. What i am trying to do is to compare this two numbers, eliminate the lower one and continue comparing until it reaches the end of the input. I dont know how to keep the higher NODN value and keep on comparing. Thank you.

code:

```
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        preLast = last;
        last = sc.nextInt();
        if (last > preLast) {
            numberOfDiffNumbers++;
        }
        if (last < preLast) {
            while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            preLast = last;
            last = sc.nextInt();
                if (last > preLast) {
                numberOfDiffNumbers2++;
                }
                if (last < preLast) {
                    break;
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: I do not ask for wholesome solutions, but only tips on what statements to use, how to code it better etc.

Comment: You should use just one loop where you restart at 1 if you find a lower number. You should have a counter and a max value, using `Math.max` for comparison (but it is easy to code that one yourself using `?:` or an if statement as well).

Comment: And you need to take in mind that the last row doesn't end with a lower number of course. So that's an additional check after you're exiting the loop...

Comment: Final hint: the idea to use `last` and `preLast` is good, but you need to think about what you do when `last` is smaller than, the same or lower than `preLast` in that single loop.

Comment: Do you need additional hints such as `maxNumberOfDiffNumbers`?

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the response, i am working on the tips u gave me and I am  actually stuck on how to hold the highest value(which is what you are asking me, so yes please). I assigned the count of the counter to a variable which i created in if(last < prelast) so it gets the current counter number and then resets the counter to 1 and start woring on a new line. I thin

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using 4 `int` variables:

```
// hold the highest NODN value here. The output of the program 
int result = 0;
// hold the NODN value of the current line here 
int numberOfIntsInTheLine = 0 
/* holds the initializing  value of a line.
 * Can hold the value of the previous number given by  the scanner.
 * Use this to check the current number against the previous number */
int initOrMinimumValueForALine= 0;
while(sc.hasNextInt() {
     int currentNumber = sc.nextInt();
     // if Current number is greater than the previous number, we keep counting 
     if(currentNumber > initValueForALine ) {
        //TODO Increment numberOfIntsInTheLine;
        //TODO Assign currentNumber to initOrMinimumValueForALine
     } 
     /** if Current number is smaller than the previous number, check NODN to see if it's the highest and stop processing the line **/
     if(currentNumber < minimumNumberForALine) { 
         if(numberOfIntsInTheLine > result) { 
             //TODO assign current NODN to highest NODN;
             //TODO break the loop; // to stop processing the current line><br/>
         }
     }          
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `// TODO` comments in the code for the parts that need to be filled, and then remove the language comment that I've added. You can use the \` characters (back ticks) for inline code such as `int`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, thanks. Still learning the ropes with the formatting. Looks okay now?

Comment: Looks better now. Personally I would not perform the second `if` after that first `if`.

Comment: Well, it's kind-of a short wiring. There's no need to process the current line if the second 'if' returns true, so I clean-up and break the loop in that block.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about how we want to process each new number that we get. Maybe we also want variables to store what the highest NODN so far is, what the number of numbers in the current row is, and what the last number we read was. Now when we read each number, any of the following are possible:

- We are reading the first number
- The next number is greater than the previous number
- The next number is the same as the previous number
- The next number is less than the previous number
- We are done reading numbers

I am trying to give some help without giving too much code, but for each of the scenarios above, think about how you would modify each of those 3 variables (highest NODN so far, length of current row, previous number)

Answer (score 0):

OK, you required a hint, so I'll show you code that is certain to be good... if filled in correctly.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
int maxElts = 0;
int elts = 0;
int last = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
// iterate over all of the integers
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    if (x > last) {
        // TODO something to elts
    } else if (x < last) {
        // we're going to have to start over
        if (elts > maxElts) {
            // TODO but if the number of elts was higher ...
        }
        elts = ?; // TODO so how many elts are in the new row we've just found?
    }
    // we don't do anything for x == last - or should we?
    last = x;
}
// OK, but 
if (elts > maxElts) {
    // TODO but if the number of elts was higher ...
}
System.out.println(maxElts);
```

Some things to take away:

- think on what you want to loop over, in this case the input integers makes most sense;
- think about what you want to remember and when you want to remember it;
- think about how to initialize the variables and how they should change state and when;
- you may have to repeat some actions or take special actions before or after the loop;
- don't test things twice, if `x > last` then certainly `x < last` does not have to be tested.

Comment: I think i filled in this right but when i run it in cmd it doesnt return any value?

Comment: `System.exit(maxElts)`. If you need to read a line of ints from command line you can use `line = args[0]` but the line needs to be placed in quotes if you do.

Comment: Or, otherwise, use an additional `Scanner` and perform a `readLine`. Splitting stuff up into separate problems is important.

Comment: I have never heard of those things so i really dont know how to implement them. In school we use Scanner(System.in). I posted the program if you could check it and tell me where is the problem. The int u is for executing this part of the code as we get an order first then in the next line the inputs. However i am grateful for your time.

Comment: So i changed the program a bit and now it still doesnt put an output but if i press any letter in the third row it prints out the correct result. Do i put system.exit after the while loop?

Comment: You exit at the end of course. You may not have found the longest row otherwise, as the current code doesn't know how many integers will follow.